# Is is OK to have locks on several file handles at the same time?

Tags: php

**Can I [flock()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) several file handles at the same time?** I remembered having read something about one single lock per process (and the second lock acquired releases the first one), but I might just be confusing this with MySQL's `GET_LOCK()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine to use multiple locks.

Just make sure you don't cause deadlocks by locking file A, and trying to lock file B, while somewhere else is locking B then trying to lock A.

Comment: Good advice, I had not imagined this possible outcome!

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely okay to `flock()` multiple file handles simultaneously.